# When do ore veins respawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have mined some ebony ore at the Throat Of The World and the ore won't come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's about 14 days of in-world real time. That being said, I don't really recall seeing any of my ores even come back (not that I was paying attention though).

After reading up on it, it may also depend on your version of Skyrim (pc, console, etc). It also depends if that ore deposit is being loaded (ie, if you are visiting it) during the mined time frame. To this end, people have reported it taking upwards to a month to respawn. You'd generally be better off just purchasing more, or finding a different deposit.